# Range(0,30) does not start with 0 if using while . Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, range

First of all, I would like to apologize if the title of the question is confusing

```
for i in range(0,30):
    while i:
        print i           
        break 

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
```

why doesn't it start with 0? if i don't use the 'while i'and just print i . . . it starts with 0 as expected.  the while loop does something weird.  what is happening? why is it not printing 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`while 0` is equivalency to `while False`. So it won't go with that one:

```
for i in range(0,30):
    while i: # while 0 == while False, so it just skips to next value
        print i           
        break
```

If you want to print the 0, check if it is actually a 0:

```
for i in range(0,30):
    while i is not False: # False == 0 but False is not 0
        print i           
        break
```

Comment: is there any way to get around this ?

Comment: @draconisthe0ry: Why do you want to?  Your while loop isn't doing anything anyway.

Comment: it's a simplification of something much more complicated.  basically what i'm doing is getting values from several sublists in several lists at specific positions

Comment: You could replace the `i` in `while i` with any expression that evaluated to a logically True value, like `while i == i`. The simplest would probably be `while True` as shown in [@paxdiablo's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20236592/355230) answer.

Answer (score 2):

`range(0,30)` *does* start with zero, it's just that because you have used, for some bizarre reason known only to yourself, the line `while i:`, it will result in falsity when `i` is zero. Hence, while the range itself produces that value, you choose to ignore it.

If, instead, you use:

```
for i in range(0,30):
    while True:
        print i           
        break
```

or, better yet, without the `while` altogether:

```
for i in range(30):
    print i
```

you'll find it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because `while` expects a boolean. 0 evaluates to false, so the while condition is not met.

Answer (score 0):

because of this:

```
while 0:
    print 'hello'
```

won't print anything.

if you really want to print at 0 as well you can instead check if it's int:

```
for i in range(0,30):
    while isinstance(i,int):
        print i         
        break
```